# Date Formatting with RegEx not able to edit after entering date

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date, date-formatting

I am new and I want to format this date but enable to format the date and moth individually, it is getting appended by '0'.

```
    var format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
var match = new RegExp(format
    .replace(/(\w+)\W(\w+)\W(\w+)/, "^\\s*($1)\\W*($2)?\\W*($3)?([0-9]*).*")
    .replace(/m|d|y/g, "\\d"));
var replace = "$1/$2/$3$4"
    .replace(/\//g, format.match(/\W/));

function doFormat(target)
{
    target.value = target.value
        .replace(/(^|\W)(?=\d\W)/g, "$10")   // padding
        .replace(match, replace)             // fields
        .replace(/(\W)+/g, "$1");            // remove repeats
}

$("input[name='birthdate']:first").keyup(function(e) {
   if(!e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode > 46))
      doFormat(e.target)
});
```

**for example**: if date is `11/12/1990` if I want to edit `12` as `11`, once I enter `1` it is automatically appending with `0` making it `11/01/1990`.

Please find the corresponding JSFiddle link [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4msunL6k/)

Comment: Why not call doFormat on onBlur event (when user leaves input) instead of when a key is pressed?

Comment: Because I am using it in a div element and its onBlur is not working there

Comment: Attempting this kind of UI with javascript is fraught as there are so many variations  in user activity that you must deal with, e.g. a user enters "01/01" then presses left cursor and delete to delete the "0", then enters "1" to get "01/11". Why not just let the user enter whatever and validate onblur?